# JS logic Algorithm isn't working and not entering else branch

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I wrote this algorithm which manipulates two Arrays. `letter` is the main one, and `fake` is a copy.

Basically I'm using loops to run into `letter` and `fake`, if they have the same 'd' value, `tmp` array is pushed with `letter[i]` values. But only once! I don't want `tmp` to have twin values inside its 'd' value.

My algorithm is running, but it seems it never enters inside my "else" to push an empty `{d : ""}` inside "tmp".

Also, I'm using `localeCompare()` which is a string method used for checking if two strings are equals, but if I'm using instead : `===` I'm getting the same results, so I'm not sure it's useful, is it ?

### PROBLEM

I don't have the expected result... My algorithm is never entering into the `else` with the second push. So doubles, remain in the final `tmp` array.

```js
// 'd' letter values : a, b, b, c, d, d

var letter = [
{a : 'one', d : 'a'}, 
{a : 'two', d : 'b'}, 
{a : 'three', d : 'b'}, 
{a : 'four', d : 'c'},
{a : 'five', d : 'd'},
{a : 'six', d : 'd'}];

// 'd' fake values : a, b, b, c, d, d

var fake = [
{d : 'a'}, 
{d : 'b'}, 
{d : 'b'}, 
{d : 'c'}, 
{d : 'd'}, 
{d : 'd'}];

/* tmp output i would like : 
{a : 'one', d : a}, 
{a : 'two', d : b}, 
{a : 'three', d : ""}, 
{a : 'four', d : c}, 
{a : 'five', d : d}, 
{a : 'six', d : ""} 
*/

function sortMyArrays(letter, fake)
{

var tmp = [];

var k = 0;
var i = 0;
var l = 0;
var size = letter.length;

do
{
    if(l !== 0)
    {
        k = l;
    }

    if(letter[k].d !== undefined)
    {   
        var lettString = letter[k].d;
        var fakeString = fake[i].d;
     
        // localeCompare() === 0 if strings are equals
        if(lettString.localeCompare(fakeString) === 0)
        {
            do
            {
                    if(i >= k)
                    {
                        // Always enter in this if
                        if(k === i)
                        {
                            tmp.push({a : letter[i].a , d : letter[i].d});
                      
                            l += 1;
                        }
                        // Never enter in the else...
                        else
                        {
                            tmp.push({a : letter[i].a , d : ""});
                     
                            l += 1; 
                        }
                    }
                    i += 1;
            }
            while(letter[k].d === fake[i].d);
         
        }
    }
}
while(k < size);

console.log("Result into tmp array is : ", tmp);

}
```

Comment: what does it do? does it enter in the if? The one associated with the else I mean

Comment: Yes it only enters in the `if( k === i)`, like if  "k" and "i" remain always the same at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really figured out what you are looking for with this algorithm, but I achieved the output you want.

```js
function sortMyArrays(letter, fake) {

  var tmp = [];

  var index = 0;
  var usedDValues = [];
  var size = letter.length;

  do {
    if (letter[index].d !== undefined) {
      var lettString = letter[index].d;
      var fakeString = fake[index].d;

      // localeCompare() === 0 if strings are equals
      if (lettString === fakeString) {
        // if usedDValues.indexOf(lettString) returns -1, that d value has not been used yet.
        if (usedDValues.indexOf(lettString) === -1) {
          tmp.push({
            a: letter[index].a,
            d: letter[index].d
          });
        } else {
          tmp.push({
            a: letter[index].a,
            d: ""
          });
        }

        usedDValues.push(lettString);
      }
    }

    index += 1;
  }
  while (index < size);

  console.log("Result into tmp array is : ", tmp);
}
```

The major change I made here was to change your unique 'd' comparison. Using an array with all of your previously used 'd' values allows you just to check that array to see if you've used it or not. 
This is not the cleanest way to do it memory wise, but its easy to read. You could also check the previous `d` values from the `temp` array to see if you've already used that `d` value.

Stick to `===` over `localeCompare` for string equality checks. `localCompare` is meant to give you the order of which string alphabetically comes first.